# int.parse instead of if else condition for adding

Tags: c#

Can we write this in one line?

```
    if (dr["Age"] == null)
    {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", 1);
    }
    else
    {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Convert.ToInt32(dr["Age"]) + 1);
    }
```

Basically add to the value if it is not null. If it is null then add a 1. I am just curious if we can do it in one line.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah, you can put all of that on one line. Just remove the line breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can by using a [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), but I wouldn't personally do it as it doesn't read well...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", dr["Age"] == null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["Age"]) + 1);
```

---

I would suggest at least break it on to a couple of lines so it's easier to make sense of, for example:

```
int age = dr["Age"] == null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["Age"]) + 1;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", age);
```

Comment: makes sense but I was just curious if we could do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could also write it like this:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", 1 + Convert.ToInt32(dr["Age"] ?? "0"))
```

More indo on ?? operator [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)